# how to show bpmn diagram as image in popover in the browser?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, bpmn

i'm using bpmn-js to convert the coming XML to diagram , how can i show the diagram in the popover in the browser .
this is how i wanted to be :

[image]

Comment: That's nice, What did you try? Provide the code you tried!